# How do i attach a method to json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have written javascript that load's bootstrap's tab dynamically when user clicks on the tab. Basically when user clicks on the tab i get the URL which preconfigured on tab as `data` attribute and then load PartialView from server using AJAX.
This javascript is generic and im using it on multiple web pages and its been working fine.

Now i need to get some data dynamically in click event handler before i make AJAX request.

Here is code

**Index.cshtml**

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#a" data-url="@Url.Action("GetA", "Home")">A</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#b" data-url="@Url.Action("GetB", "Home")">B</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#c" data-url="@Url.Action("GetC", "Home")">C</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="a" class="tab-pane fade">
        </div>
        <div id="b" class="tab-pane fade">
        </div>
        <div id="c" class="tab-pane fade">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Common Javascript**

```
var tabStrip = (function () {
var module = {};    

 module.configureTabs = function (options) { 

    $(".nav-tabs > li > a").click(function (e) {     

        // I want to call a method here      ???????
        // something like options.getData(); ???????
        // Once i get data I would append this data to url

        var $tab = $(this);            
        var url = $tab.data("url");
        var href = $tab.attr("href");
        $(href).load(url, function (result) {               
            // raise onLoad event
            if (options != undefined && options.onLoad != undefined) {
                options.onLoad($tab);
            }
        });

        // raise click event
        if (options != undefined && options.onClick != undefined) {
            options.onClick($(this));
        }
    });        
}

return module;

})();
```

**This is how im calling configureTabs from Index.cshtml**

```
$(function () {      
    tabStrip.configureTabs({
       onLoad: function(e){
         // do something here
       }  

       // how do i attach a method here that returns some data. ????
       // tabStrip.configureTabs function needs invoke this method inside click event handler ???

    });
})
```

How do i attach a method to `options` parameter. I should be able to call this method from click event handler

Comment: "_...that returns some data_" Where exactly you want to receive that data?

Comment: You are already doing that with `onClick`. Why don't you just repeat that pattern?

Comment: @MattSpinks onClick, onLoad these are events not methods. and tabStrip is raising these events.

Comment: @Teemu method will get some values from textbox, dropdownlist and return those values.

Comment: @LP13, `onLoad` and `onClick` **are** methods. And `tabStrip` is invoking these methods. There are no events being raised in this code. An event would be `click` and `load`. But `onLoad` and `onClick` are functions that are invoked.